# CVXPY stuck in Compilation step during solving linear program

Tags: linear-programming, solver, cvxpy

I'm trying to solve a linear program with 869532 variables and 8869 constraints in CVXPY. The CVXPY gets stuck in the Compilation session right before passing the problem to the solver. Here's the verbose log:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  Compilation                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Jul 05 11:23:23 AM: Compiling problem (target solver=ECOS).
(CVXPY) Jul 05 11:23:23 AM: Reduction chain: Dcp2Cone -> CvxAttr2Constr -> ConeMatrixStuffing -> ECOS
(CVXPY) Jul 05 11:23:23 AM: Applying reduction Dcp2Cone
(CVXPY) Jul 05 11:23:25 AM: Applying reduction CvxAttr2Constr
(CVXPY) Jul 05 11:23:26 AM: Applying reduction ConeMatrixStuffing
```

After, say half an hour, nothing happens.
So, my question is whether there is an option to possibly bypass the reduction or facilitate this process.

PS. I have tried different solvers resulting in no effect.

Comment: Maybe you have triggered a bug or located some code with extremely bad performance. I would pose the question at https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/discussions

Comment: Also posted here github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/discussions/2170